# Generate a random sound with a button

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

I am working on a iPhone app.

So I have a view controller that has a random button, an UIImage, a play button for the sound and a UILabel. Then I press the random button I use the switch function to use a case that change the UIImage and the UILabel randomly and this works perfect but I don't know how to do that the sound generated by the play button to be different.

I mean, is this even possible? I know how to use arc4random() to play something else every time I press the play button but I want the sound to be changed when I press the random button.. Hope it is understand what is my issue and I am sorry but I will upload the code that I made soon as possible but for the moment I don't have access at it.

Comment: Take random files and play it on button click

Comment: I will prefer to have the same button evry time I press random that play a different sound in correlation with the image and the label. It is about translating

Comment: You can use the texttoSpeech conecept

Comment: Do you mean that you actually want to digitally effect the sound? or just play a random sound each time the button is pressed?

Comment: random sound, I have an mp3 file for every expression

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To play a random sound each time the button is pressed you could use `arc4random()` as you mentioned with a switch statement that selects a different mp3 file url each time - something like this.

```
int random = arc4random_uniform(3);
NSString *soundName;

switch (random)
{
   case 0:
     soundName = @"soundone"
     break;
   case 1:
     soundName = @"soundtwo"
     break;
   case 2:
     soundName = @"soundthree"
     break;
   case 3:
     soundName = @"soundfour"
     break;
}

NSString *soundURL = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:soundName ofType:@"mp3"];
AVAudioPlayer *player = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:soundURL] error:NULL];
[player play];
```

To avoid playing the same sound twice in a row you can put the variables in your `.h` adding an extra one to hold the previously generated random number then use a `while()` statement to make sure the newly generated random number is not the same as the last one like this..

**.h**

```
int previousRandomNumber;
int random;
```

**.m**

```
random = arc4random_uniform(3);
NSString *soundName;   

if(random == previousRandomNumber){
    while(random == previousRandomNumber){
        random = arc4random_uniform(3);
    }
}

  previousRandomNumber = random;

    switch (random)
    {
       case 0:
         soundName = @"soundone"
         break;
       case 1:
         soundName = @"soundtwo"
         break;
       case 2:
         soundName = @"soundthree"
         break;
       case 3:
         soundName = @"soundfour"
         break;
    }

}

NSString *soundURL = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:soundName ofType:@"mp3"];
AVAudioPlayer *player = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:soundURL] error:NULL];
[player play];
```

Comment: Thank you for feedback but I want when I press the random button somehow the other button on the view to play if pressed a different sound than before the random button was pressed. I hope it is possible and I explain myself clear enough

Comment: You want to prevent the same sound being played twice in a row?